# Given a list of date and value pairs, efficiently sum the values by date

Tags: downvalues

I have a list of date & value pairs.  There can be multiple entries for each day.  Sample data can be generated with the following:

```
maxDays = 10;
date = AbsoluteTime[{2013, 5, 13}];
dateValuePairs = Flatten[Table[{date + day * 86400, value}, {day, maxDays}, {value, 10}], 1];
```

The sample data looks like:

```
{{3577478400, 1}, {3577478400, 2}, ... {3577478400, 10},
 {3577564800, 1}, {3577564800, 2}, ... {3577564800, 10}, 
 ...
 {3578256000, 1}, {3578256000, 2}, ... {3578256000, 10}}
```

I am trying to sum the values for the same day.  With the sample data above, I expected to see ten days, each with a value of 55 .

I tried the following:

```
Clear[sumByDay];
Map[ 
  (sumByDay[#[[1]]] =
     If[ValueQ[sumByDay[#[[1]]]],
      sumByDay[#[[1]]] + #[[2]],
      #[[2]]
      ]) &, dateValuePairs];
DownValues[sumByDay]
```

... and I expected it to return:

```
Out[]= {HoldPattern[sumByDay[3577478400]] :> 55, HoldPattern[sumByDay[3577564800]] :> 55, ... HoldPattern[sumByDay[3578256000]] :> 55}
```

... however I receive:

```
$RecursionLimit::reclim: Recursion depth of 256 exceeded. >>

Out[]= {HoldPattern[sumByDay[3577478400]] :> 1 + sumByDay[3577478400]}
```

`sumByDay[#[[1]]] + #[[2]]` must not be being evaluated as I expected, see below:

```
In[]:= a[3577478400] = 1
In[]:= a[3577478400] = a[3577478400] + 2
...
In[]:= a[3577478400] = a[3577478400] + 10

Out[]= 1
Out[]= 3
...
Out[]= 55
```

### And the Question of Efficiency ...

I am sure I can accomplish this less efficiently. As I am equally sure that it can be done more efficiently. i.e. :

```
Map[(day = #;
   {day, Total[
     Transpose[Select[dateValuePairs, #[[1]] == day &]][[2]]]}
   ) &, Sort[DeleteDuplicates[Transpose[dateValuePairs][[1]]]]]
```

The number of days defined by `maxDays` in the sample data example will grow at a const rate.

Comment: You can use `GatherBy` as in `{#[[1, 1]], Total[#[[All, 2]]]} & /@ 
 GatherBy[dateValuePairs, #[[1]] &]`.

Comment: A variant of this has been asked several times on this site... please try searching the [tag:list-manipuation] tag for `Gather` and `GatherBy` (and look through the results for one that matches)

Comment: `Gather` & `GatherBy` ... that is what I was missing.

Comment: And for using a wrench to hammer the nail in ... Any idea where I went wrong with `DownValues`?

Comment: The LHS of your internal function is not correct yet it manages to send you into infinite recursion...

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick and dirty way to grab the data and tally it up:

```
data = Gather[dateValuePairs, #1[[1]] == #2[[1]] &];
sumSet[list_] := {list[[1, 1]], Plus @@ (#[[2]] & /@ list)}
sumSet /@ data

(*
{{3577478400, 55}, {3577564800, 55}, {3577651200, 55}, {3577737600, 
  55}, {3577824000, 55}, {3577910400, 55}, {3577996800, 
  55}, {3578083200, 55}, {3578169600, 55}, {3578256000, 55}}
*)
```

The second argument to `Gather[]` is a request to gather those pairs that have the same date.

Comment: It will usually be far more efficient to use `GatherBy`, where applicable, than the second argument of `Gather`.

Answer (score 0):

In versions 10+, you use `GroupBy`

```
List @@@ Normal @ GroupBy[dateValuePairs, First->Last, Total]
```

> {{3577478400, 55}, {3577564800, 55}, {3577651200, 55}, {3577737600,  55},
>      {3577824000, 55}, {3577910400, 55}, {3577996800, 55},
>      {3578083200, 55}, {3578169600, 55}, {3578256000, 55}}

or  `Merge`:

```
List @@@ Normal @ Merge[Total][Rule @@@ dateValuePairs]
```

> {{3577478400, 55}, {3577564800, 55}, {3577651200, 55}, {3577737600,  55},
>      {3577824000, 55}, {3577910400, 55}, {3577996800, 55},
>      {3578083200, 55}, {3578169600, 55}, {3578256000, 55}}